# How to implement counter field in MYSQL table for each date without transactions?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

I have a request table where I store date time, messages and counter.

```
Date        | Counter
2014/12/03  | 1
2014/12/03  | 2
2014/12/03  | 3
2014/12/03  | 4
2014/12/03  | 5
2014/12/04  | 1
2014/12/04  | 2
```

The counter field stores incremented count for each date starting from 1 and on date change it resets to 1. I have implemented it by checking the last row count with date condition and added the next counter in request table.

But now I see some duplicate values in counter field for same date. How do i resolve it without transactions.

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: mysql version is 5.6.10

Comment: Is there any virtue in storing the counter when you calculate it on demand?

Comment: Yes I need to calculate this on demand because I create some identifier from this count.

Comment: You can't resolve this without transactions or table locks. You might be able to do it with a trigger and/or another table, but that would also be a transaction ;)

Comment: @Vatev Wouldn't it slow down the app if I get so many request at the same time.

Comment: It will slow it (by an unknown amount), but you can't make realtime multithreaded counters without locking.